# How to make calls to a server in WPF

Tags: wpf, sockets, client-server

I'm a noob in WPF so please bear with me. I wanted to do a client - server application. The client has a UI and the server is a console application.

Is there any way that the client can communicate with the server? I know there were "sockets" in Windows Forms, which could send/receive data. Are they available in WPF also? And if yes, could anyone provide me with a simple example on how to use them? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should check out WCF to go along with WPF.  You can still use sockets if you want to, but WCF is probably going to be a lot easier for you.

Comment: In an over-simplification, the "WPF" part of this is really just the UI, and the code to bind that UI.  You still have the entire .NET Framework available to you for the backend communications stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments Microsoft has a whole technology dedicated just to that.  Link to beginners guide to Windows Communication Foundation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784

Answer (score 0):

we use WCF for client-server communication and wpf for the client. works like a charme.